# Project Motorola: setting up and solving an equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Stuck on a homework project in a highschool college algebra question.  I'm given the following information:

Tact time is the average time to pick and place one part.  Throughput is the number of boards per hour, or placements per hour.  Variables include:

> $n$: The number of boards per hour
>
> $p$: The number of parts per board
>
> $C$: The tact time
>
> $L$: The load-unload time
>
> $M$: The mark reading time

Throughput is calculated by:  $$TH(n) = \frac{n}{Cnp+L+M}$$

Setting:  $C=0.2 \mbox{ seconds}$, $L=5 \mbox{ seconds}$, $M=1 \mbox{ second}$, and $p=50 \mbox{ parts per board}$, I get the equation $$TH(n) = \frac{n}{(10n+6)}$$  I'm supposed to find out the minimum number of boards per panel ($n$) that will allow me to have a $TH(n)$ of at least $300$.  So I've set $$300=\frac{n}{(10n+6)}$$ and tried to solve for $n$.  I get $-0.6002$.  This just doesn't make sense to me, that is, having a negative answer for a throughput time seems odd to me.  Looking at the equation, and graphing, it seems there is a limit of throughtput of $1/10$...which again looks suspect.  Pretty much nothing about this scenario makes sense to me as throughput, from that equation, seems to always be less than $1/10$.

Note:  This is from Sullivan and Sullivan, College Algebra 2nd Edition, page 68 Project Motorola, "How Many Cellular Phones Can I Make?"  Similar to what is found here:  http://wps.prenhall.com/wps/media/objects/1257/1287289/ChapterR/Pm_howma.pdf

Comment: Looking over your link, it looks like $n$ is boards per panel, not hour.  Do I have that right?

Comment: Yes, and that correction probably saves the day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that $TH(n) = \frac{n}{10n + 6}$ will get as high as $300$ for positive $n$.  However, if you look at the dimensions, the function you have for throughput is in boards per *second.*  So, you can certainly never make $300$ boards per second. (In fact, as you noticed, you can never do more that $0.1$ board per second.  The factory can only move so fast, after all.)  $300$ boards per *hour* is possible, however.  To find the $n$ that makes this possible, convert $300$ boards per hour to boards per second, and then put that number in for $TH(n)$.